# Can I preload a mission into my drone (navio2) so it can execute it without being connected to a ground station by telemetry during flight

Tags: quadcopter, ardupilot

The question really speaks for itself. I don't have any way to connect with my navio2, running ardupilot, during flight (except a radio controller if things go wrong). Could I still make my drone autonomously follow a certain path, take pictures, etc. ?

Comment: are you really seeking a simple yes or no answer?

Comment: @jsotola Well obviously no, a simple yes or no wouldn't really help me.

Comment: then please edit your post so that it is not a yes/no question

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, see:
https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/auto-mode.html?highlight=mission
https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/learning-ardupilot-storage-and-eeprom-management.html

but you need to be careful to specific parameters in Ardupilot, so as not to terminate the flight inadvertently when you loss connections (caution only do this if you have a very specific reason for doing so, it can be dangerous to continue because you may loose control of your drone, i did NOT test these settings):

AFS_DUAL_LOSS:
AFS_RC_MAN_ONLY:
AFS_RC_FAIL_TIME:
AFS_MAX_COM_LOSS:

For explainations for the parameters refere to here:
https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/parameters.html

I'am not liable about any damage you may cause by doing so!